# Power BI Ranking

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to rank my table values as 1,2,3,4,5 etc however when using the RANKX function I have noticed that if my values are the same for example 4 values are 25 then the ranking would be for example 1 for all 4 of those values. But I would want them to be 1,2,3,4 etc.

[image]

I have used this DAX measure: [image]

The values are commonly going to be the same for multiple "short descriptions" I am not bothered about the order of the ranking if they are the same. Just making sure the rank rating is in order from 1-15.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: In SQL, you would use `ROW_NUMBER()`instead of `RANK()`.  It is not clear if you want a SQL solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Within Power BI would be preferable

Comment: are you sure you want rank or row number? I don't see anything wrong with the example, the values with 25 should be ranked 1 as it's not specified how to break the tie. If you want the row number, you can add a index column using power query

Comment: I am wanting to show the top 5 "Short Description" based on the highest rating.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible in your case to do the Aggregation in Power Query part, you can create your row_number/index there as well. If I guess correct, your value in column **Fifth Value** is measure and you are doing aggregation with a group by applied on value **Short Description**. So you are getting **Sort Description** wise **Fifth Value** and you need a row number based on values for **Fifth Value**, right?

If the above is correct, you have to do the **Sort Description** wise aggregation in **Power Query** and add the **Index** there for your filtering purpose in the report.